# Проблема с изучением Java

Tags: java, книги, java-8, java-10

Появилось желание начать изучать Java, но столкнулся с 1 проблемой: На данный момент актуальная версия Java - 10, но книги для обучения по ней написаны под 8 версию. Прочитал, что с каждой версией меняется очень многое. 
Вот и сам вопрос: стоит обучаться по старым книгам или нет?

Comment: До сих пор актуальная версия 8. И от 8 до 10 будет легко перейти.

Comment: Актуальная это что значит? 90% пишут на 8. И на 10 вряд ли перейдут в ближайшие несколько лет. Учи 8 и не парься.

Comment: Технологии развиваются довольно инертно. Это связанно с не только с программированием. Производители железа, разработчики систем и платформ всё тут взаимосвязано. Многие пользователи хотят работать на тех системах, которые выпущены давно, многие не хотят каждый год покупать новое "железо", покупать новую систему или ставить новую платформу. Поэтому старые версии актуальны долгое время.